# How do i keep geometry nodes instanced meshes when exporting mesh to fbx?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, instances, unreal-engine

In blender I create a mesh "cube" and create instances of it using Alt+D and place them randomly in the scene. If i export the collection of meshes as an fbx and import it into unreal engine I will only get one mesh imported which is correct and it is instanced in the locations where i set them up in blender. I am trying to do the same with the output from geometry-nodes but i cant figure out how do do this so far?

[image: Default way to create instanced meshes in Blender]

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible and you would have to use the *Realize Instances* node to get an exportable geometry.

Comment: yes that was what i was thinking, i hoped there was something i was missing.

I have created a partially working script here to help address this.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305914/create-instanced-linked-duplicate-of-mesh-respecting-selected-meshes-location